# Spark for loop with Rdd transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
For iterator i from 0 to n 
  Create data frames using i as one of the filter criteria in the select statement of sparksql 
  Create Rdd from dataframe 
Perform multiple operations on rdd
```

How do I make sure that for loop works? I am trying to run the Scala code on a cluster.

Comment: Can you add some code? From your pseudo-code it is unclear about the nature of `rdd`. Is it a concatenation of multiple `rdd`s created in the loop. Or is it something else?

Comment: maybe I ask why are you doing that ? a for a piece of code as well ? also what's does n represent ?

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest to run it locally in some test suite (as in scalatest). If you are not the type of unit/integration testing, you could simply do a `DF.show()` on your data frames as you iteration though them. this will print a sample from each data frame.

```
(0 until 5).foreach(i => {
  val df = [some data frame you use i in filtering]
  df.show()
  val df_rdd = df.rdd
})
```

Comment: In order to get the `DataFrame` as `RDD` you can use: `df.rdd`